# new angular router - autoscroll equivalent

Tags: angularjs, angular-new-router

ui-router and the 1.4 angular router supported `autoscroll="true"` to enable the page to scroll to top of page on navigation to another route.  Does anyone know how to do this with the [new angular router](https://github.com/angular/router)?

ng-outlet does not appear to have an autoscroll property and the router itself does not appear to have any events I can listen to so I can hook this up manually.

Answer (score 1):

A manual way of doing this is:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
  document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
});
```